# Error when starting the Application Insights Agent for Java

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-java-sdk

I have configured my environment as described in this link for the Application Insights Agent for Java:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-agent

I configure an environment variable so that the Java Options are set with the option "-javaagent:" set to the directory where the agent jar file is located and the associated AI-Agent.xml file.  I continue to get a startup error:
"[Fatal Error] AI-Agent.xml:1:10: The processing instruction target matching  [xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed."

The configuration file contains the default values from the above link.  I have also tried other times where I have removed everything except for the outer tags but still get the same error so I do not believe the config file is the issue.  Does anyone know what this message means?

Comment: could you please expand, a bit more. This is not something I have seen happening. What java version your app is on and what kind of application you have?

Comment: This is a custom application that uses SpringBoot.  I am running java version 1.8.0_191-b12.  It does not matter how I start my application I get the same error.  For example, different ways I have tried are: mvn springboot:run ..., mvnDebug springboot:run, or java  -javaagent:C\applicationinsights-agent-2.3.0.jar -jar myjar.war.  I continue to get this error:   [Fatal Error] AI-Agent.xml:1:10: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.